# Android create and initialize window without showing it

Tags: android, dialog, setcontentview

I have a dialog with some UI elements in there. This dialog is created and shown at some point later on via `show()`. I can create the dialog with the default constructor `Dialog(Context)`. But my content view is only set on `onCreate` which is called after `show()` function. This causes NPE when I try to modify UI elements like this:

```
public void showNumber(String number)
{
    labelNumber.setText(number);
    show();
}
```

But if call change the above function as below, it works most of the time. (Sometimes it fails if the phone gets slower because `setContentView` wouldn't be called by the time it executed `setText`)

```
public void showNumber(String number)
{
    show();
    labelNumber.setText(number);
}
```

How do you create the dialog and set content view without showing it at all. If I call `setContentView()` manually, it will be re-called when i call `show()` for the first time.

Comment: Store `number` in a variable, wrap `show();` in a `new Handler().post` call and set 'labelNumber'  to `number` in `onCreate`.

Comment: @SaschaKolberg It helped. I stored number in variable and overriden onStart() to set my text which is called after onCreate() until I find a proper way to create it.

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is call `create();` on the dialog when you construct it.

When you call show it will create the dialog only if `create();` hasn't been called and then call `onStart();` on the dialog. Finally it will attach the dialog to the window.

Something like:

```
Dialog myDialog = new Dialog(context) {
    protected void onCreate() {
         super.onCreate();
         doYourThing
    }
};
myDialog.create();
```

I'm assuming you're doing logic in onCreate, because, in Dialog it's just an empty method for subclasses to override.

onCreate:
http://androidxref.com/5.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/Dialog.java#37

show:
http://androidxref.com/5.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/Dialog.java#254

Pre API level 21 (if you can't use an AlertDialog.Builder) you should be able to use `onRestoreInstanceState` to do what you want to do, like this (this is a hack):

```
Bundle myBundle = new Bundle();
myBundle.putBoolean("android:dialogShowing", false);
myBundle.putBundle("android:dialogHierarchy", new Bundle());
myDialog.onRestoreInstanceState(myBundle);
```

Info:

http://androidxref.com/4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/Dialog.java#411

Comment: create() is what I was looking for but it requires API level 21 which I can't make use of it.

Comment: An alternative way would be to call onRestoreInstanceState on the dialog, I'll show you the code.